# CPU Usage of a query in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, cpu

My main aim here is to get the %CPU usage of a given query so that I can find the bottlenecks in my program. Although I have been using [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) to get things like query execution time and memory usage, I don't see a way of getting the %CPU utilized. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried using `sys_getloadavg()` function like so but I don't think it returns what I want

```
$cpu_load = sys_getloadavg();
Log::info("FIRST: " . $cpu_load[0] . '% / 100%'. '\n');
Log::info("FIRST RECENT: " . $cpu_load[1] . '% / 100%' . '\n');
Log::info("FIRST RECENT-ISH: " . $cpu_load[2] . '% / 100%' . '\n');

// Perform Queries here
DB::table('stems')->insert($data);

$cpu_load = sys_getloadavg();
Log::info("SECOND: " . $cpu_load[0] . '% / 100%'. '\n');
Log::info("SECOND RECENT: " . $cpu_load[1] . '% / 100%' . '\n');
Log::info("SECOND RECENT-ISH: " . $cpu_load[2] . '% / 100%' . '\n');
```

This is the log output:

```
[2021-11-19 04:15:03] local.INFO: FIRST: 1.544921875% / 100%\n  
[2021-11-19 04:15:03] local.INFO: FIRST RECENT: 2.01220703125% / 100%\n  
[2021-11-19 04:15:03] local.INFO: FIRST RECENT-ISH: 1.78173828125% / 100%\n  

[2021-11-19 04:15:27] local.INFO: SECOND: 1.45166015625% / 100%\n  
[2021-11-19 04:15:27] local.INFO: SECOND RECENT: 1.96142578125% / 100%\n  
[2021-11-19 04:15:27] local.INFO: SECOND RECENT-ISH: 1.76806640625% / 100%\n
```

Notice that the second %CPU usages are lesser than the first which does not seem right because I would expect the %CPU to increase after the query is executed.

Comment: The result should be correct because the insert is already done and the cpu has nothing to do anymore. You will need to have a process log the cpu usage in the background so that during the execution the CPU usage is measured.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. I am currently doing as you suggested. But I was just wondering if there is a "native" way in Laravel to get the CPU usage in Laravel for a query. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will not be executed till the insert operation is completed. You might see the spike in CPU when insert is in progress and not after it has been completed. So I believe the results are valid.
To verify what I said above you can login into server machine and check CPU when insertion is in progress and also after that. Had sys_getloadavg() been asynchronous you might have got surge in the values printed in the logger.

```
$cpu_load = sys_getloadavg();
Log::info("SECOND: " . $cpu_load[0] . '% / 100%'. '\n');
Log::info("SECOND RECENT: " . $cpu_load[1] . '% / 100%' . '\n');
Log::info("SECOND RECENT-ISH: " . $cpu_load[2] . '% / 100%' . '\n');
```